# Detect if the notificationbar is pulled down

Tags: android, notifications

Some weeks ago a friend showed me an alarm clock app on his Galaxy Note2 where the alarm stops if you pull down the notification bar.

I would like to know how to get the pull-down event for the notificationbar, i tried googling and also searching here on SO. All i found was "how to show your notifications" or "pulldown refresh for listview" and similar.

I hope someone has achived that yet. or can give me a hint.

Comment: It is possible using the accessibility service. This is what I've used:  if (accessibilityEvent.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED && accessibilityEvent.getPackageName().equals("com.android.systemui")&&(accessibilityEvent.getClassName().equals("com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar$ExpandedDialog")||
     accessibilityEvent.getClassName().equals("android.widget.FrameLayout")||accessibilityEvent.getClassName().equals("com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService$ExpandedDialog"))){   seems to work for all phones but not an easy way to do it!

Comment: You can detect when notification shade is pulled down only if your Activity is in the foreground and its **onWindowFocusChanged** method is called.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how to get the pull-down event for the
>   notificationbar

I'm almost certain there's no such thing. However, I would bet that pulling the notification bar down sends your app into the "onPause" state.

Comment: i also want to get the info when my app is not visible. so i dont think there will be a onPause for my app. i have a service that does stuff in background and showing infos in notification. the problem is that some of the infos need to be computed, and i dont want to compute those infos, if they are not needed, as the computation is in some conditions heavy. so i would like to update the notification if the user pulls notificationbar down.

Comment: onPause is not called on pulling down Notification bar.

Comment: onResume is also not executed after hide the notification bar

Comment: What if the notification is a foreground Service, then your app's Activity is not even running.